# Regular Expressions for Linux - scan the Apache HTTPD access log for all the response code other than 200

Tags: regex, grep

This is a question about grep and regular expression.

If I want to see all the requests whose response is a 200 code, I can do:

```
grep -e '^.* - - .* .* .* .* .* 200' access_log
```

Quite easy peasy.

But what if I want to retrieve all the requests whose response is NOT a 200 code?
I would like to be able to do that with only one grep instruction. Is that possible?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: That's quite a horrible regex. It will lead to no end of backtracking and must be wildly inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `-v` option for `grep`. This inverts the matches, so it returns all the lines that do *not* match the pattern.

So like this:

```
grep -v [pattern] [file]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this:

```
^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\[[^]]+\]\s+"(?:GET|POST|HEAD) [^ ?"]+\??[^ ?"]+? HTTP/[0-9.]+"\s+200
```

and then invert the result as Daniel Egeberg suggested.

With comments and capturing groups, courtesy of [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com):

```
^((?#client IP or domain name)\S+)\s+((?#basic authentication)\S+\s+\S+)\s+\[((?#date and time)[^]]+)\]\s+"(?:GET|POST|HEAD) ((?#file)[^ ?"]+)\??((?#parameters)[^ ?"]+)? HTTP/[0-9.]+"\s+(?#status code)200
```